# Ubuntu Samba share for Windows and Mac

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac

> File Server: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with SMB and SSSD configured to join our Windows domain

> Mac OS Sonoma, latest version, with a local profile (managed by MDM), connecting to the server using the appropriate username and password

This has been a long standing issue that I've never managed to figure out.

When a user drags folder(s) from their Mac to the Ubuntu file server, the root folder(s) all get created with incorrect permissions, `rw- rws r-x`, not allowing them to copy the files within those folder(s) - The user is part of the group that should have full access to the folder they're copying files to, and Finder's Right Click > New Folder grants the corrent permissions `rwx rws r-x`.

What's baffling me is that if the user logs in to their Windows PC, they'll be able to copy the folders and files without any problems, so whatever it is, it's specific with the Mac.

Essentially what it boils down to:

- Mac user Right Click > New Folders into the Server share = folders get treated as folders.
- Mac user drags a folder from Finder into the Server share = sent folders get treated as files.

Could someone perhaps guide me as to what I might have done wrong in my `smb.conf` in case I've not set something right? After attemping to change I run sudo systemctl restart smbd.service (incase I'm missing another step)

```
[archive]
   comment = Archive folder
   path = /mnt/archive
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   directory mask = 0755
   force directory mode = 2775
   create mask = 0665
   force create mode = 0665
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide links = no
   veto files = /._*/.DS_Store/
   vfs objects = streams_xattr
```

Upon further testing by changing the directory/create and both force modes to 777, and trying again but with directory/force directory set to 0775, it seems like samba is just not respecting the directory permissions properly; folders are being created as 777 (as if they're files).

Comment: This sounds almost like an issue with the client itself, and how it handles the 'drag' action. I guess the SMB client is fairly built in so not sure if you can manage the version. Does it behave consistently on newer/older mac clients?